# No sound in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in VirtualBox?

Tags: 16.04, sound, lubuntu, alsa

I am running a Mac OS X 10.11.6 with a VirtualBox 5.1.2. I installed Ubuntu (and Lubuntu) and both have had no sound after "successful" installs, only problem being Ubuntu is slow and, Ubuntu and Lubuntu have no sound. Do keep in mind I'm new to Linux. I have searched online and have found people saying their problems were fixed with the alsamixer thing and the puvacontrol thing and reloading/uninstalling-reinstalling the alsa (what is alsa?) but mines wasn't. I tried everything and was hoping these forums could help me.

Thanks.

P.S. if you have any instructions, please make sure it's readable by a Linux-noob.

Comment: Sounds like a VBox issue.

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/1106839/audio-not-working-in-win-10-in-virtualbox-virtualbox-5-1-2-guest-additions-m

Answer (score 3):

Open the Virtualbox main window and click on the vm's you want to check and take a look at the **Audio** section on the list on the right.  If it says anything other than the audio system Mac uses, change it to that and run the vm to see if the sound is restored.

For example, on one of my vm's it had been changed to **null audio driver**.

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 23.10, things are now possibly broken due to lack of pipeware? I couldn't find an option that worked with the official Windows virtual machine: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/ Windows always says "No output devices found"

Answer (score 2):

***This may help to fix the error:***

1. In Ubuntu first click on the unity launcher option to show this menu:
   [Unity Launcher Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c4H9.png)
2. Type in 'Settings'
3. Click on the "Sound" option
4. Click on the relevant device once as shown in this picture: [Sound Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRqkF.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you already checked the audio controller settings and the audio device shows up as working in the virtual machine I found that the newer versions of VirtualBox do have checkboxes in the audio settings of the virtual machine to activate the actual audio output. It was turned off by default for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you hit this bug?  https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15659 It seems to be related to v5.1.2 of Virtualbox and AC97